# Using prepare statement in php form and not logging in when enter information

Tags: php, prepared-statement

**This is my code**

```
 if(isset($_POST['submitlogin']) && !empty($_POST['usernamelogin']) && !empty($_POST['passwordlogin']))
{
    $inUsername=$_POST["usernamelogin"];
    $inPassword=$_POST["passwordlogin"];
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Username ,Password FROM users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $inUsername, $inPassword);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($inUsername, $inPassword);
    $stmt -> fetch();
```

**I think Here is the problem in bind->result.could You please tell me what it is**

```
$hash = $inPassword;
    $passwordcheck = password_verify($inPassword, $hash);
    if($hash == $passwordcheck)
    {
    $_SESSION['username']=$inUsername; 
    ?>
    <script>
    window.location.href = 'someaddress.php';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<h1>Incorrect username or password</h1>"; 
    }
```

.
        }

Comment: `password_verify` verifies that __password__ and its' __hash__ are the same.

Comment: `password_verify` takes two arguments ~ password and hash. `boolean password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )` ~ you seem to be passing the password twice

Comment: @u_mulder now iam using different ..But error still exists

Comment: @RamRaider can u please add code

Comment: Using different __what__?

Comment: @u_mulder can you please add code..

Comment: @RamRaider shows you function definition. Is it so hard to understand what parameters should you pass to it?

Comment: How do you initially hash the password? Can you show that code or the hash... it is that hash you need to use in the `password_verify` function as the 2nd parameter

Comment: @RamRaider sir take a look on updated code..is that what you say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken directly from the [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) as an example of the sort of data you would be passing in to the function.

### password_verify

> Verifies that a password matches a hash
>
> boolean password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )

```
<?php

    // See the password_hash() example to see where this came from.
    $hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

    if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
        echo 'Password is valid!';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid password.';
    }

?>
```

### password_hash

> password_hash — Creates a password hash
>
> string password_hash ( string $password , integer $algo [, array $options ] )

```
<?php

    /**
     * We just want to hash our password using the current DEFAULT algorithm.
     * This is presently BCRYPT, and will produce a 60 character result.
     *
     * Beware that DEFAULT may change over time, so you would want to prepare
     * By allowing your storage to expand past 60 characters (255 would be good)
     */
    echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";

?>

The above example will output something similar to:

$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a
```

I still have PHP 5.3.2 so `password_verify` and `password_hash` are unavailable to me until I rebuild my laptop but I think you would use it like this perhaps:

```
if( isset( 
        $_POST['submitlogin'],
        $_POST['usernamelogin'],
        $_POST['passwordlogin']
    ) && !empty( $_POST['usernamelogin'] ) && !empty( $_POST['passwordlogin'] ) ){

    $inUsername=$_POST["usernamelogin"];
    $inPassword=$_POST["passwordlogin"];

    /* select two fields but only use username in where clause */
    $stmt = $con->prepare("select `username`, `password` from `users` where `username` = ?");
    if( $stmt ){

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $inUsername );
        $stmt->execute();

        /* bind the results */
        $stmt->bind_result( $username, $hashed_password );
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

        /* use the given password and the returned hashed password - see if they match */
        if( password_verify( $inPasswordDB, $hashed_password ) ){

            $_SESSION['username']=$inUsername;
            header( "location: UserProfile.php" );

        } else {
            echo "<h1>Incorrect username or password</h1>"; 
        }

    } else {
        echo "statement failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: From where $hash password came ..from database?

Comment: Totally in a fix ..Don't understand how it works..Iam using simple login without Prepare and it is working properly but with prepare it is complicate everything

Comment: Error while logging in..I entered right username and password...But it is still giving an error "Incorrect username or password"

Comment: can you confirm that the password stored in the database is indeed hashed using `password_hash`?

Comment: Okayyyy Sir..now i  understand  what was the actual  problem ..thanks sir..now it is working fine..thanks for your effort..

Comment: :) pleasure ~ glad you have it sorted and can progress

Comment: you are awesome ..Thanks once again sir